# How to resize an image?

Tags: iphone, image-resizing

I have taken an image from `UIImagePickerController`, but the file looks too big to be transferred through internet, I'd like to resize the image. I couldn't find any method related to the image process.

Any recommendation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a context of the desired size using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext()`, then draw the image to the context using UIImage's `-drawInRect:` method, and finally use `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` to pull a new UIImage back out.